# Recuperar conteúdo entre tags personalizadas utilizando RegEx

Tags: php, regex

Estou precisando capturar o conteúdo que está entre uma tag personalizada que possui um identificador padrão, como por exemplo: `<:item>Conteúdo</item>`, porém não estou conseguindo com que o fechamento dessa tag também seja personalizável, e no caso estou conseguindo apenas desta maneira: `<:item>Conteúdo</end>`, mantendo um fechamento padrão para todas as tags do mesmo conteúdo.

RegEx atual:

```
preg_match_all("~<:(.*?)>(.*?)</end>~si", $conteudo, $retorno);
```

Qual seria a expressão regular para encontrar a tag de abertura e a sua tag relativa de fechamento? mesmo que exista uma herarquia de pais e filhos com o mesmo nome de tag.

Comment: Você pretende usar a tag `<:item>`, ou somente o conteúdo?

Comment: se você não for obrigado a usar RegEx, porque não utiliza SimpleXML?

Comment: Como você monta essa string? Ela não tem nenhum padrão, nem XML, nem HTML...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Se você pretende usar SOMENTE o conteúdo da tag, você pode usar a ER abaixo, no caso ela remove tudo entre `<>`:

```
$conteudo = '<:item>Conteúdo</item>';
print_r( preg_replace("/<.*?>/", "", $conteudo) );
```

Exemplo disponível no [**ideone**](http://ideone.com/qg2pI3)

---

2) Se você pretende usar a própria tag e o conteúdo, você pode usar a ER abaixo:

```
$conteudo = '<:item>Conteúdo</item>';
preg_match_all( '~<.+?>(.+?)<\/.+?>~' , $conteudo , $retorno );
echo $retorno[1][0];
```

Exemplo disponível no [**ideone**](http://ideone.com/26X8p2)

---

### Atualização

Passo 1) substituir `<...>` por um marcador `|`
Resultado: `|HEADER||MAIN|ITEM||`

Passo 3) remover marcadores duplos `||` por simples `|`
Resultado: `|HEADER|MAIN|ITEM|`

Passo 4) quebrar a string nos marcadores e filtrar os valores nulos
Resultado: `array( 1 => 'HEADER' , 2 => 'MAIN' , 3 => 'ITEM' )`

```
$string = '<:header>HEADER</header><:main>MAIN<:item>ITEM</item></main>';

// passo 1
$string = preg_replace( '/<.*?>/' , '|' , $string );

// passo 2
$string = preg_replace('/\|+/', '|', $string);

// passo 3
$string = array_filter( explode( '|' , $string ) );
```

Note que isso **NÃO** é o ideal, apenas resolve um problema. A forma que você gera essa string é inadequada. Veja um demo no [**ideone**](http://ideone.com/TMsiRb)

Comment: O segundo exemplo é praticamente o que eu preciso, com o porém de não funcionar para tags filhos, como por exemplo:

`$conteudo = '<:header>HEADER</header> <:main>MAIN <:item>ITEM</item></main>';
preg_match_all( '~<.+?>(.+?)<\/.+?>~' , $conteudo , $retorno );
var_dump($retorno);`

Retorno:
`array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(24) "<:header>HEADER" [1]=> string(30) "<:main>MAIN <:item>ITEM" } [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(6) "HEADER" [1]=> string(16) "MAIN <:item>ITEM" } }`

Comment: Adicione essa informação à questão!

Answer (score 0):

não sei se é desta forma que você quer, mas funciona:

```
$html = "<:item>ConteúdoA</item><:valor>ConteúdoB</valor><:tag>ConteúdoC</tag><:teste>ConteúdoD</teste>";
preg_match_all("/<:(.*?)>/", $html, $arrTag);

foreach($arrTag[1] as $tag)
{
echo $tag;
preg_match_all('/<:'.$tag.'>(.+?)<\/'.$tag.'>/sm', $html, $conteudo);
print_r($conteudo);
}
```

Comment: O problema é que as tags não podem ser definidas diretamente, no caso apenas o padrão é o demarcador <:TAG_AQUI></TAG_AQUI>, então é preciso encontrar a tag de fechamento a partir da segunda tag.

Comment: Oi, Motonio, acontece isto aqui com as respostas que só tem código: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Wnj5W.png . É legal uma explicação, ainda que breve, porque seu código resolve o problema. Vide [answer].

Comment: fiz de outra forma, espero que seja do jeito que você quer

Comment: Se você define a TAG na regra no loop, não precisa disso `<:'.$tag.'.*?>`.

Comment: @PapaCharlie eu fiz desse jeito caso o autor precisa saber de qual tag ele esta pegando